# Output Conditional Sum Of Spark DF Column To Variable

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The goal is to sum the value in the 'points' column if the player's name begins with 'D' and they are younger than 20.

| name | age | points |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Diego | 31 | 1 |
| Giorgio | 27 | 4 |
| Pat | 30 | 7 |
| Doug | 15 | 7 |

I've tried the following (trying to get it working) but keep getting errors:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F 
point_sum = df.agg(F.when(F.col('age') < 20), F.sum('points')).collect()[0][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You would want to filter the data you want before doing aggregation.

```py
(df
    .where(F.col('name').startswith('D') & (F.col('age') < 20))
    .groupBy(F.lit(1))
    .agg(F.sum('points').alias('total_points'))
    .collect()[0][1]
)
# Output: 7
```

Comment: I previously thought filtering would be less efficient but looking into it after seeing your response has led me to believe its a good option.

Answer (score 1):

Good Try. Keep Trying.
One alternative is to use `filter` with `substring`.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import substring

# Filter both age <20 and name starts with 'D'.
point_sum = df.filter("age < 20 and substring(name,1,1)=='D'").select('points').agg(sum('points')).collect()[0][0]
print(point_sum)
```

Output:
[image]